# Render to texture and then to screen cause flickering

Tags: sdl2

So I have my class `vItem` which has a vector (consider elements like layers) of textures, origin rects and destination rects plus other stuff.
Basically whenever I update any of the layers in the vector I redraw everything on an internal texture which is then displayed on the screen, here's the function that draws on the texture:

```
void vItem::draw(){
    if(sprites.size() <= 0)
        return;

    // This calculates the dimensions of a rectangle big enough to contain every texture
    SDL_Point size = calculateSpriteRect();

    if(size.x <= 0 || size.y <= 0)
        return;

    // If the final texture does not exists or its dimensions are different from the new rectangle I destroy it and recreate it
    if(final_sprite == NULL || size.x != final_sprite_size.x || size.y != final_sprite_size.y){
        if(final_sprite != NULL)
            SDL_DestroyTexture(final_sprite);
        final_sprite = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, size.x, size.y);
        SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(final_sprite, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
        final_sprite_size = {size.x, size.y};
    }

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, final_sprite);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    for(int i = 0; i < sprites.size(); i++){
        SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(sprites[i].sprite, sprites[i].alpha);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, sprites[i].sprite, &sprites[i].source, &sprites[i].bounds);
    }   
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);
}
```

The problem comes after this function: I have a child class of `vItem` called `vButton` where I have two layers of text (one normal and the other on for when the mouse is over the button), and when I update alpha values of the layers to hide one level and show the other one `draw()` is called. This transition causes an instant flickering (black background right before drawing).
When I removed vSync I noticed that this wasn't happening anymore, but I need vSync.

**UPDATE:**
Ok... Apparently if I remove both `SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);` the flickering is gone and everything is rendering correctly, but I can't understand why. This is the final function:

```
void vItem::draw(){
    if(sprites.size() <= 0)
        return;

    // This calculates the dimensions of a rectangle big enough to contain every texture
    SDL_Point size = calculateSpriteRect();

    if(size.x <= 0 || size.y <= 0)
        return;

    // If the final texture does not exists or its dimensions are different from the new rectangle I destroy it and recreate it
    if(final_sprite == NULL || size.x != final_sprite_size.x || size.y != final_sprite_size.y){
        if(final_sprite != NULL)
            SDL_DestroyTexture(final_sprite);
        final_sprite = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, size.x, size.y);
        SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(final_sprite, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
        final_sprite_size = {size.x, size.y};
    }

    //SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, final_sprite);
    //SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    //SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    for(int i = 0; i < sprites.size(); i++){
        SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(sprites[i].sprite, sprites[i].alpha);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, sprites[i].sprite, &sprites[i].source, &sprites[i].bounds);
    }   
    //SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);
}
```

How can the renderer keep information about the texture on texture rendering and texture on screen rendering at the same time (since I have only one `SDL_RenderPresent()` left at the end of my game loop)? Is it meant to work like that?

Comment: You are calling `SDL_RenderPresent` twice with a `SDL_RenderClear` in between, is that intentional?

Comment: @AndyM I use that renderer to draw textures to screen too, so if there are any, I render the renderer then clear it, draw on texture and render it again

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out! So I was working on my SDL2 Rendering code using a buffer texture with `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET` which **showed the same problem as yourself (aka did not work)** and it looked like this:

```
if(SDL_RenderClear(Global->renderer))
{
    /*  Error... omitted for readability... */
}

/* render all my textures, such as cars, ships, anything on the window... */

SDL_RenderPresent(Global->renderer);

setRendererTarget(NULL);

if(SDL_RenderCopy(Global->renderer, Global->textureBuffer, NULL, NULL))
{
    /*  Error... omitted for readability... */
}

SDL_RenderPresent(Global->renderer);

if(SDL_RenderClear(Global->renderer))
{
    /*  Error... omitted for readability... */
}

setRendererTarget(Global->textureBuffer);
```

The gist of my and yours to an extent code was:

- Render Clear
- Render all textures to screen
- Render Present
- Switch Render Target to Window
- Render Copy Texture Buffer to Window
- Render Present
- **Render Clear**
- Switch Render Target back to Texture Buffer

I've highlighted in bold the issue. We're clearing the screen AFTER a Render Present not BEFORE. But doesn't the game loop just clear at the top of the loop, rather than at the bottom?

```
while(1)
    clear?
    Render Stuff...
    clear?
```

No, because at the end of a game loop is an SDL_Delay, which means in a 1/60th of a second, the screen is cleared, rather than AFTER the delay, which is 1 game tick and nothing is presented on the screen for "real time".

```
while(1)
    clear!
    Render Stuff...
    SDL_Delay!
```

`SDL_RenderClear` clears the target (not internal backbuffer). The implementations for this is system Dependant here: https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=RenderClear+%3D+&type=

So the actual list of operations needs to be:

- Render Clear
- Render Copy
- Render Present
- FPS Delay

For any rendering. Case closed!