# How to check if renderer is not empty?

Tags: sdl2

I have a `SDL_Renderer` in SDL2 that I use both to render textures on screen and to render textures on textures, my problem is that when I render to texture the renderer may have some content in it which needs to be drawn, but if it's empty and I call `SDL_RenderPresent()` on it the screen flickers. So how can I check if there's something drawn inside the renderer?

Comment: Track it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so from what I understood, when you are rendering to a texture there's no need to flush the renderer before, not even after; that's why there isn't such function to check if the renderer is empty or not.

So the steps are these:

```
// This draws inside the renderer's buffer
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, source, bounds);
// This switches to rendering on texture
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, target_texture);
// Apparently this is enough to draw on the texture (so there's no buffer I guess?)
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture2, source, bounds);
// This switches to rendering on renderer buffer
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);
// This flushes the renderer buffer (so only the SDL_RenderCopy() before rendering on texture)
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

See my [other question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110911/render-to-texture-and-then-to-screen-cause-flickering) for this.